# Material design parallax scrolling - view completely disoriented

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-recyclerview, material-design

I was trying parallax scrolling recently, in an activity, where the image drawable and all the texts are passed as intents, and the image is shown above the toolbar, as in parallax. But the view gets completely disoriented, though the parallax scrolling is working. I'm attaching a few screenshots to show the problem.

I'm suspecting that maybe its a theme error, but I just cant get out o it. Please help.

[image: Not scrolled yet]  [image: Scrolled down]

The activity

```
package com.example.sayan.kennel;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.support.v7.graphics.Palette;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PetViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout;
    ImageView imageExtra;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pet_view);

        Intent intent=getIntent();
        String titleExtra=intent.getStringExtra("title");
        String detailExtra=intent.getStringExtra("details");
        TextView titleView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleText);
        TextView detailView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detailsText);
        titleView.setText(titleExtra);
        detailView.setText(detailExtra);
        imageExtra= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageExtra.setImageResource(intent.getIntExtra("image",0));

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        collapsingToolbarLayout= (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(titleExtra);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        setPalette();

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Just sad", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }
    private void setPalette(){
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageExtra.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        Palette.from(bitmap).generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
                int primaryDark = getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
                int primary = getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary);
                collapsingToolbarLayout.setContentScrimColor(palette.getMutedColor(primary));
                collapsingToolbarLayout.setStatusBarScrimColor(palette.getDarkVibrantColor(primaryDark));
            }
        });
    }

}
```

The XML layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.sayan.kennel.PetViewActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/ani_cat_seven"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Dummy Text"
            android:id="@+id/titleText"
            android:textSize="42sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Dummy Text"
            android:id="@+id/detailsText"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_stars_white_48dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The styles

```
<resources>>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Divider">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">1dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">?android:attr/listDivider</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

That part of the manifest

```
<activity
            android:name=".PetViewActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_pet_view"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".AdoptionActivity" />
        </activity>
```

Comment: If I remove the android:fitsSystemWindows="true" property from the coordinator layout, the problem goes, but the system app bar is completely white.